# Media Queries to keep menu and sidebar from merging with header/body

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, media

[This is the website, and more specifically, the page](http://camillagabrieli.com/blog/).

I'm currently working on a responsive theme, which has media queries, but something about the CSS modifications I've made, are preventing the menu (top right in gold), and the sidebar (this only exists on the blog page, but it is important... it's the box at the right of the content block) from merging with the header/title/left-hand content. It shows up on the ipad mini, the regular ipad 4, but it is okay in an android browser screen. You can observe the issue by resizing the browser.

```
@media only screen and (min-width:768px) {
.site-navigation .nav-menu {
 display: block;
}
}@media only screen and (max-width:767px) {
.menu-toggle {
display: block;
}
}@media only screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:959px) {
.wrap {
max-width: 728px;
}
```

That is the media screen css. The respective divs are all positioned relatively. Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this problem? Any code tidbits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I see is that this HTML is not closed:

```
 <div id="header" onclick="location.href='http://camillagabrieli.com
```

That needs to be fixed first. Try adding outlines to your CSS:

```
* { outline: 1px dashed black }
```

I find that helps a lot when it comes to seeing what's actually wrong with the different floated elements. There are quite a few things wrong with your arrangement and your CSS. You don't need to relatively position all of these things.

To fix the main content section:

Add the following to #main:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

And make #content and #sidebar-primary like this:

```
#content {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    min-height: 50px;
}

#sidebar-primary {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    border-top: 1px solid #222;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
    height: 50%;
}
```

I'm not sure why you had margin-top: -460px; in your code, but that was what was breaking it, as was the fact that #main wasn't actually containing #content and #sidebar-primary. The code still needs cleaning up, but this will fix it more immediately.

Does this help?